# Edit the contents of a gen.gz file using linux, awk or sed

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a `gen.gz` genetic data file with 6000 columns. The data looks like:

```
1 1:13380:C:A 13380 C A
```

I want to edit the second column so that it looks like:

```
1 1:13380 13380 C A
```

I want to delete four characters in the second column.

The input is a `gen.gz` file and I want the output to be the same.

Comment: Are the 6000 fields in the file space-delimited?

Comment: Yes, they are space-delimited.

Comment: Is the file gzipped or is the file extension just a coincidence?

Comment: The file is gzipped.

Comment: There are millions of rows and about 6000 columns, gzip compressed. Is there a way to edit gzipped files directly or do they have to be uncompressed on the go and then compressed back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the fields are delimited by a space character, you can decompress the file, feed it through `awk` to do the modification, and then compress the resulting data to a new filename. This can be done in a single pipeline without storing the uncompressed data on disk.  When the operation is done, inspect the result and replace the original with it if it looks ok.

```
gzip -d -c gen.gz |
awk '{ sub(":[^:]*:[^:]*$", "", $2); print }' |
gzip -c >new-gen.gz

# look at new-gen.gz, and then

mv new-gen.gz gen.gz   # only if you want to discard the original data!
```

The `awk` code could be done in many different ways. I've chosen to remove the last two `:`-delimited strings from the second field rather than chopping off the last four characters, as you suggested.  If you always have only single characters there, the regular expression `:[^:]*:[^:]*$` could be written as `:.:.$` instead.

Since you are modifying the data in a compressed file, you can't really do a in-place edit of the file (as with `sed -i`).